# c.programing, code dosent work

Tags: c, runtime-error

my program is to check if a number is a perfect number 
I have a runtime eror please help 
and I am using notepad++ if it matters

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input=0;
    int i=0;
    int counter=0;

    printf("enter a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    for (i=0;i<=input;i++)
    {
        if (input%i==0)
        {
            counter = counter+i;
        }
    }
    if (input==counter)
    {
        printf("%d in a perfect number\n", counter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not a perfect number\n", input);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `for (i=0;i<=input` --> `for (i=1;i<input`

Answer (score 5):

`input % i` returns the remainder when dividing `input` by `i`. But you can't divide a number by `0`, so `input % 0` results in undefined behavior.

Change your loop to start from `1` rather than `0`. Also, you should stop *before* `i` reaches `number`, because the number is always a divisor of itself, but that shouldn't be included in the sum when adding up the divisors (how could a number be equal to the sum of itself and all the divisors?).

```
for (i = 1; i < number; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have `input%i == 0`  and `i` is being initialized to `0`.  This is essentially dividing by `0` on the first iteration which is probably where the error is coming from.